# I do not see a verb here! why?: "As relative newcomers, ...."

Tags: grammaticality

> **As newcomers to the South**, a place where their climate could be equally inhospitable, the navajo created these art forms to affect the world ...

The author is trying to say that the Navajo used the symbolism and beauty of their works of art to improve their life in an often inhospitable environment. But I think a verb is missed in the bolded sentence, Am I right? Or maybe I cannot understand the meaning of the bolded clause. I am confused.

Comment: The unit of text you've bolded isn't a sentence. One way you can see that is precisely that it doesn't have a verb (though that's not guaranteed to be the case: there are plenty of short sentences, such as "Hello!" that don't have verbs) and it's separated from the rest of the text by a comma, rather than a full stop, question mark or exclamation mark.

Comment: The link does not work for me. I do appreciate your including a link, though, as many people don't.

Comment: @AlanCarmack It thinks I'm a crawler: `We have detected that you may be a crawler, or opening up to others to do the title link, from the formal channels exercises, have questions, please contact your administrator!`

Comment: @AlanCarmack: And me (in what looks like Chinese).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a very complex sentence that starts with two appositive phrases before it gets to the actual sentence.

The *actual* sentence here is:

> The Navajo **created** these art forms to affect the world around them, not just through the recounting of the actions symbolized, but through the beauty and harmony of the artworks themselves.

The first two sections (set apart by commas) are explanatory, extra information.

The bold section from your question describes the Navajo

> As relative newcomers to the Southwest

This could be read, instead as

> The Navajo, **relative newcomers to the Southwest**, created these art forms to affect the world around them...

The second section describes "the Southwest"

> a place where their climate, neighbors, and rulers could be equally inhospitable

So, no verbs are necessary. The sentence is correct as written.

If you want a complete rewrite of the sentence, it could be written:

> The Navajo, relative newcomers to the Southwest - a place where their climate, neighbors, and rulers could be equally inhospitable,  **created** these art forms to affect the world around them, not just through the recounting of the actions symbolized, but through the beauty and harmony of the artworks themselves.

"The Navajo" is the subject and "created" is the verb.

Comment: Does "relative" in here mean  "seeming to be something when compared with others'?

Comment: Yes. It means that in the grand timeline of when people arrived in the Southwest, the Navajo have been there for less time than other indigenous groups.

Comment: If you use a dash after "Southwest", shouldn't there also be a dash after "inhospitable"? It seems like the punctuation in both of those locations – be they commas or dashes – should match.

Comment: @J.R. I don't know... I know that I can't use both a dash and a comma... the comma is to end both sections.

Comment: Revelant: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/9816

Comment: @flornquake related but not quite the same... The problem is that I need to close the appositive but I can't use both the dash and the comma ... I suppose that it would be simpler if I made the second appositive phrase into a parenthetical as I **can** use both the comma and the end parenthesis.  So, it would be: *The Navajo, relative newcomers to the Southwest (a place where their climate, neighbors, and rulers could be equally inhospitable),* But it's not really a parenthetical. I only used the dash to set it apart more strongly.

Comment: For that aside in the middle of the sentence, the opening and closing marks should match (i.e. if you began with a comma, then end with a comma; if you began with em dash, then end with em dash). Em dash sources: [s1](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html), [s2](http://www.really-learn-english.com/em-dash.html), [s3](http://grammarist.com/grammar/emdash/)

Comment: @xgord but I'm ending **two** asides at the same time - the first one has a comma and the second one has the dash... I opted to close the main aside with the comma rather than the one with the dash.... honestly, this is probably why the author chose to order the sentence the way they did.

Comment: Yeah that's a complex problem. [This site](http://www.amnation.com/vfr/archives/021137.html) indicates some disagreement on that matter. But in both cases the answers indicate that the em dash should definitely be used. They just disagree on whether an additional comma is also needed.

Comment: The same disagreement occurs between the two answers from the QA linked by @flornquake. So I'd say that the second em dash is needed.

Comment: I'm going to be honest... The rephrasing is just there as an example of how to rephrase the sentence... and it's not even integral to my answer. I never had any intention of it being scrutinized in this way... I don't think that the example on that link @xgord is the same as the usage here - it's not in the same place (being before the dash, not after it). I'm sort of frustrated that this is such a big deal and I'm honestly tempted to just remove the entire example if people are going to get so hung up over it and DV my answer because of something this idiotic.

Comment: There's no need to get frustrated. You have a well-written answer (which I had already upvoted, as did many other people). The rest is just a discussion over whether or not the punctuation in the final example is correct. Part of the fun of this site is in determining what is proper usage in English.

Comment: For further punctuation discussion: [chat link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43383/discussion-between-xgord-and-catija).

Comment: Would you define what an "actual sentence"  is?